# WCF app Deployed on Win7 Machine and get connection refused error

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client

I have created a Sync Framework application based on the [following sample from microsoft](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sync/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3762) and deployed it to a new Windows 7 machine for testing.  The app runs ok but when I attempt to communicate I get the following error:

> Could not connect to
>   http://localhost:8000/RelationalSyncContract/SqlSyncService/.
>   TCP error code 10061: No connection
>   could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it
>   127.0.0.1:8000.

I am wondering if there is something I am missing.  This is my first experience using WCF and followed microsoft sample code.

I have disabled the firewall and opened port 8000 for both TCP and UDP.  Not sure what to look at next.  Below is my App.config file if this helps:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="32768" />
  </system.web>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WebSyncContract.SyncServiceBehavior" name="WebSyncContract.SqlWebSyncService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="largeMessageHttpBinding" contract="WebSyncContract.ISqlSyncContract">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/RelationalSyncContract/SqlSyncService/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <!-- We are using Server cert only.-->
        <binding name="largeMessageHttpBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="204857600">
          <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="1000000"/>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WebSyncContract.SyncServiceBehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
         <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/></startup></configuration>
```

Thank you, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think it may have something to do WCF Service Host not starting.. so need to find how to start this on the deployment machine.. visual studio starts this automatically..

Answer (score 0):

Its possible to analyse if the service is starting correctly or not, by enabling **Message logging and Trace**:

```
    <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Warning, ActivityTracing">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
        propagateActivity="true">
        <listeners>
          <add type="System.Diagnostics.DefaultTraceListener" name="Default">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
          <add name="ServiceModelTraceListener">
            <filter type="" />
          </add>
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
    <sharedListeners>
      <add initializeData="Your_svclog_file_here"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelMessageLoggingListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
      <add initializeData="Your_svclog_file_here"
        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
        name="ServiceModelTraceListener" traceOutputOptions="Timestamp">
        <filter type="" />
      </add>
    </sharedListeners>
    <trace autoflush="true" />
  </system.diagnostics>
```

In this case, the Trace is able to log "Information". Its important to see the channels creation.

To analyse the svclog file, you can use the **Service Trace Viewer** - Microsoft Windows SDK, usually in C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin\SvcTraceViewer.exe